# How to get response body while generating the rest docs?

Tags: spring, rest, documentation, httpwebresponse

[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HreZX.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGnOv.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSkTS.png)

While hitting uri on postman here response body is coming, but while spring rest docs generating documents no response body is coming only showing 200 Ok. Is it a cors issues? If you have any idea, Please help me on this.

Issues
200 OK ==== Response

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers

This is the cors issue. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).